# Double transpile with ES6 bundler?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jspm, es6-module-loader, transpiler

My current workflow, which is ES6-like but does not use module loading, is to use a Gulp task that runs my TypeScript code through `tsc`, producing **ES6** output, and then again through Babel, producing ES5 output. I do this because TypeScript does not yet support async/await when outputting ES5 directly.

I would now like to start doing proper ES6 module-loading, which means I need a compatible bundler.

Does JSPM, Webpack, or anyone else support this double-transpiling process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack supports it - you can chain loaders. It would be sothing like following in webpack loaders configuration:

```
{test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['babel', 'ts-loader']}
```

More about webpack loaders: https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html

Comment: Awesome! Crossing my fingers that someone else answers with a jspm solution, which is my preference, but if not, you win. :)